# Why are comments not working dynamically?

Tags: bug, comments

Nowadays when commenting on any site I need to refresh the page and then my comment appears.

Sometimes when I interact with a site again I found my comments have disappeared.

Why is this happening?   When will this be fixed?

---

I'm using firefox quantum 63.0 on linux mint kde plasma.

Comment: By "deleting automatically", do you mean "not being submitted", or "posting them, but they keep getting deleted later"? Also, can you please [edit] in your browser and OS configuration?

Comment: Yes sometimes when I interact with a site again I found my comments are disappeared.

Comment: In that case, that's probably a separate cause; likely, your comments are being flagged by members of the community, causing them to be automatically deleted. As it's a separate issue, you should probably ask this on the per-site meta of the site where this is happening.

Comment: Ok I can understand but what about the main issue I have mentioned in my question. Dynamic comments.

Comment: Can you please edit in your browser and operating system version?

Comment: So is it configuration issue?

Comment: I'm using firefox quantum 63.0 on linux mint 18.3 kde plasma.

Comment: It seems from looking above that you *can* leave comments.  Which websites are you referring to? And how long have you noticed this peculiar behaviour?

Comment: I can comment but doesn't work dynamically I need to refresh page and then comment is appearing.  I'm referring Buddhist stack exchange and I've been facing this since two months.

Comment: Even here on meta it's same.